# Giving onBindViewHolder listener AlertDialog

Tags: android

Can someone please help me? I'm having hard time getting my AlertDialog to show. I am making AlertDialog depending on what item is clicked.

If someone could direct me to what I have to do to make this alert dialog work. Here is also a link of screenshot of my problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnNTa.png

Here is code:

```
    package com.mario.restaurantcroatia;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.List;

public class LandingRestaurantAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LandingRestaurantAdapter.RestaurantViewHolder>{

    public interface PositionClickListener
    {
        void itemClicked(int position);
    }

    private Context context;
    private List<LandingRestaurants> restaurantsList;


    public LandingRestaurantAdapter(Context context, List<LandingRestaurants> restaurantsList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.restaurantsList = restaurantsList;
    }

    @Override
    public RestaurantViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
        View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.landing_items, null );
        RestaurantViewHolder holder = new RestaurantViewHolder( view );
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RestaurantViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        LandingRestaurants restaurant = restaurantsList.get( position );

        holder.imageView.setImageDrawable( context.getResources().getDrawable( restaurant.getPicture() )  );

        //onClickListener for landing page town cards
        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener( ) {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            /*    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );

                final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.landing_click_on_town_alert_dialog,null);
                ImageView location = (ImageView)view.findViewById( R.id.location );
                ImageView currentRestaurant = (ImageView)view.findViewById( R.id.restaurant );
                ImageView history = (ImageView)view.findViewById( R.id.history );
                ImageView attractions = (ImageView)view.findViewById( R.id.attractions );

                mBuilder.setView( view );
                AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.show();*/



            }
        } );



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return restaurantsList.size();
    }

    class RestaurantViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView;


        public RestaurantViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super( itemView );

            imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById( R.id.picture );

        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's due to mismatch of object name onClick method view and your inflater view,so change the view iflater object name `view` to `dialogView` or  else

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.landing_click_on_town_alert_dialog,null);
```

change it to likebelow

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );

            final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.landing_click_on_town_alert_dialog,null);
            ImageView location = (ImageView)dialogView.findViewById( R.id.location );
            ImageView currentRestaurant = (ImageView)dialogView.findViewById( R.id.restaurant );
            ImageView history = (ImageView)dialogView.findViewById( R.id.history );
            ImageView attractions = (ImageView)dialogView.findViewById( R.id.attractions );

            mBuilder.setView( dialogView);
            AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
            dialog.show();
```

Comment: Here is a screenshot. If fonts are to small I'll make them bigger.

https://i.imgur.com/GgokXM3.png

Comment: okay may i show your  xml file for landing_click_on_town_alert_dialog?

Comment: ok try to remove first linerlayout background may be it causes the problem. just remove and try it

Comment: `ractangle_background_alert_dialog_landing_page` remove this drawable and try

Comment: Thank you very much. This was the problem. My ractangle_background in drawable had (v24) in it, standed out. Created new one and it works. Thank you so much, was trying whole day, now I can continue my project.

Can you tell me what does v24 stand for?

Comment: happy to help you. you may also accept my answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the transparent background?

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from( view.getContext());

                final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                View viewdialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.landing_click_on_town_alert_dialog, null, false);
                ImageView location = (ImageView)viewdialog.findViewById( R.id.location );
                ImageView currentRestaurant = (ImageView)viewdialog .findViewById( R.id.restaurant );
                ImageView history = (ImageView)viewdialog.findViewById( R.id.history );
                ImageView attractions = (ImageView)viewdialog.findViewById( R.id.attractions );

                mBuilder.setView( viewdialog );
                AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
                dialog.show();
```

Comment: Still nothing. Screenshot  https://i.imgur.com/vzh9cKo.png

It always says my inflating row is wrong.  view = inflater....

Comment: Still nothing. https://i.imgur.com/VHxHoQV.png

Is it even possible to call alert dialog to inflate inside inflater class?

Comment: What is your log cat saying?

Comment: Please upload the text and not an image, I can't see

Comment: There is a problem with your xml layout that why the inflation is failing

Comment: Not sure how, it says message is to large. Has a lot of space in it if I try to copy paste

Comment: Your dialog implementation isn't the problem but your landing_click_on_town_alert_dialog xml is. What is it's code